# OpenIdDict automatic signing key generation

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I'm trying to archieve an automatic signature and encryption key rollover in openiddict.
Unfortunately the library reads keys directly from `IOptions<>` and will also validate that a key is configured during configuration. This restricts me from starting without keys, detecting that and create a key during startup (or when needed).

There are some samples in the issues of openiddict, but all samples are sync and my usage pattern is more or less async - at least the loading and saving of the keys is async. I can place them in a cache and read them synchronous, but then the keys will still not be initialized upon startup.

Does anyone know a suitable solution, to configure the keys as soon as they are available, e.g. how to asynchronously load and change config at runtime?

Comment: Would IOptionsSnapshot  solve your issue?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-ioptionssnapshot-to-read-updated-data

Comment: I thought about Snapshot and Monitor, but fail to see, how I'd load anything "late bound", when the _validation_ of the options occurs during configure.